# Downgrade admin account by mistake

Tags: wp-admin, user-roles

I made a huge mistake changing my admin account role from 'administrator' to 'Basic User'. Don't know what to do. Any suggestions how should I proceed to retrieve my account role back again, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, this should help:

1. Open your database (with phpmyadmin, navicat, etc)
2. Open the wp_user table and have a look for the ID of your admin user (usually 1)
3. Open the wp_usermeta table and search for the row that has the user_id of your user
4. paste the following string into the meta_value field of the row:

`a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`

that should be it:
login again and the user should be administrator again.

One advice though: Some plugins put their admin rights into that field too - those are lost after that. But deactivating/activating of the plugins could solve that.

Best way to avoid all that: Create a new user in the user table and give this user the new rights. With the new admin user you could give the old admin user the admin status back again.

br from Salzburg,

Johannes

Comment: That was fast and clean. Thank you so much! It's 'administrator' again.